# OrchardCMS pull down to visual studio

Tags: orchardcms

If I have a version of Orchard installed on a server via Microsoft Web App Gallery from my hosting provider, Is there a good way to pull down the instance of orchard for local visual studio development?

Answer (score 4):

When doing Visual Studio development, **always** use [full source](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-source-enlistment) from Codeplex. The WebPI package is intended to use out-of-the-box when you **don't** want to perform any coding.

In your case it's quite tricky, though, but doable. The best approach would be to

1. Grab the full source as described [here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Setting-up-a-source-enlistment),
2. Grab the source from your server
3. Copy the files from 2. to *src/Orchard.Web* subdirectory found in 1. (overwriting any existing stuff)
4. Open up the */src/Orchard.sln* solution in VS and add references to any custom modules you had on your server (2.) that are not in the Orchard core (1.). You will find those under the */src/Orchard.Web/Modules* subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with Piotr's answer, but if you just need to make some tweaks then the code from WebPi should work okay with [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/).

I wouldn't use this solution for module development, but if you just want to tweak a simple theme or run the site locally then it's worked for me.